# ADF dataflow: to assign null to a negative result

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to load null if the total hours is less than previous total hours else the difference

```
iif(lesser(TOTAL_HOURS, PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS),null(),TOTAL_HOURS-PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS)
```

It gives me expression could not be evaluated.

Not all rows have values for these fields, some of them are null. They are numeric fields in database.

I just want to replace negative results with null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the document [iif](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#iif) it says

```
iif(<condition> : boolean, <true_expression> : any, [<false_expression> : any]) => any
```

> Based on a condition applies one value or the other. If other is
> unspecified it is considered NULL. **Both the values must be
> compatible**(numeric, string...).

Now as per your expression:

```
iif(lesser(TOTAL_HOURS, PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS),null(),TOTAL_HOURS-PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS)
```

since first value you have mentioned is of type `null` it expects `TOTAL_HOURS-PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS` must also return a same type `null`

**What you can try is:**

```
iif(lesser(TOTAL_HOURS, PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS),toInteger(null()),TOTAL_HOURS-PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS)
```

OR

```
case(TOTAL_HOURS < PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS, toInteger(null()), minus(TOTAL_HOURS,PREVIOUS_TOTAL_HOURS) )
```

[image]

[image]